# jQuery .ajax function, exactly how to use it

Tags: php, jquery, sql-update

I am using wordpress and need to update a tables data with jQuery ajax, I have the below code which posts the data successfully.

```
jQuery('#update-<?php echo $row->id; ?>').live('click', function (){

    var myname = jQuery('input[name="name_two"]').val();
    var mystep = jQuery('#step<?php echo $row->id; ?> option:selected').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-content/plugins/gates/updateGateData.php",
        data: {name_two:myname, step_two:mystep},
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Data updated');
        },
    });
});
```

Now my problem resides on what to put in the updateGateOption.php file to post to update the database.

Thanks Guys for the responses! So I have this now:

```
$name = $_POST['name_two'];
$step = $_POST['step_two'];

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 
'gate_options', 
array( 
    'step' => $step, 
    'name' => $name,
    'image_path' => 'new-img-path',
    'option' => strtolower($name),
    'value' => strtolower($name),
)
);
```

But the values are not being updated, plus I cannot see any errors..

Comment: put single quotes on name_two and step_two.

Comment: Just put there your normal PHP code. You are posting data so you have to use `$_POST` to get your data. @shashank the quotes are not necessary. It is a Javascript object

Comment: On php page you can grab value of data using $_POST['name_two'] and $_POST['step_two'];

Comment: added an edit to the above post

Comment: Create a variable of `$wpdb->update` and print the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code in updateGateOption.php:

```
$name = $_POST['name_two'];
$step = $_POST['step_two'];
```

Now run your query,

```
if(mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET field1= $name, field2=step WHERE 1=1 AND YOUR_CONDITION")){
    echo "Data updated successfully";
}else{
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
```